# How to make wget use existing local files no matter what

Tags: wget, mirror

I'm using wget mirror option to mirror a complete website

```
wget -mk https://test.com
```

When I stop wget and resume it afterwards with the same command, it will keep issuing HEAD-commands for all the files already downloaded. This is to check if the files have changed since the last download and retrieve them again if the file on the server is newer. I would like to turn off this functionality, meaning:
If a local file already exists, wget should use the local file always and not even issue a HEAD-command to validate modification time or filesize.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. There is no switch in Wget as of this writing that will allow you to skip testing the local files. And there is a very good reason for that. If Wget did not validate each file again, one or both of these two issues will occur:

1. The last file that was being downloaded is now incomplete and corrupt. But you have no indication of this or which file it was. This also means that Wget will not be able to parse and follow any links from this file. So you will likely end up with a partial mirror and nothing to tell you that.
2. Some of the files changed on the remote end between your last attempt and the current one. Without validating the modification times again, what you're getting is an inconsistent mirror. Since the half the mirror is old and other half is new, this is new, there could be all sorts of interesting issues that result out of this.

And anyways, a HEAD request is very fast, since it needs very little bandwidth. So I don't see why that would be the choke point in any pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to accomplish this by _sligthly_ modifying the source in src/http.c?

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this by _sligthly_ modifying the source in src/http.c and disabling the HEAD-request completely, the function always returning that the local file is up-to-date? I'm trying to mirror a dynamically created site (php). The HEAD-command on ALL php files will return an empty modification date so they will all have to be downloaded again no matter if anything changed. Apart from this, the site contains quite a lot of pages, so want to mirror it step by step on multiple days - the second step picking up exactly where the first step left off and so on.

Comment: Remember the first point I made. The last file you were downloading, _will_ be broken. There is no way feasible to resume the download from exactly the same location without writing state information, which is something Wget tends to not do. You can modify src/http.c to prevent doing this, but it is not entirely trivial. In case the file exists, you'd ave to read it to memory and skip the entire http_loop.

Comment: Ok, will look into http.c a bit. If I find an easy solution, I will post it. Apart from this your answer is right :-)

Comment: You can also drop by on IRC at #wget  on Freenode or drop us an email on bug-wget@gnu.org if you need some more help.